# Finding a notary in Mexico City

Tags: legal, mexico, mexico-city

My employer just handed down an urgent requirement to provide a notarized proof of my eligibility for employment in the U.S.A. I'm in Mexico City now. Is it possible to notarize something here? How can I find a notary recognized in the U.S.A?

Comment: I'm aware of [this question](http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2499/444), which on the outset asks in general how to find a notary in a foreign country, but the answers are specific to France and Italy.  If a more general answer can be provided, I would love to close my question as a duplicate of the other.

Comment: I seem to recall seeing signs for notaries all over the place in Mexico City. They stood out because I couldn't recall ever seeing one in my own country.

Comment: @hippietrail: I'll be sure to keep my eyes open, then, and start asking around.

Comment: Try some of the areas that are full of tiny cheap offices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

While a quick search shows a few around the Colonia Roma area, if you want to be sure about the legality of one that's recognised in the United States as well (and I don't know what the rules are there), then the best bet may be to use the Notary Services available at the US Embassy in Mexico City.

[Notarial Services and Appointments](http://mexico.usembassy.gov/eng/citizen_services/notary-services.html)

> Notary services are by appointment only from 2:00 p.m. to 3:00 p.m. To
>   make an appointment, click [here](https://evisaforms.state.gov/acs/make_calendar.asp?postcode=MEX&appcode=1&type=3&servicetype=NS&First=Y).  If you have multiple documents to be
>   notarized you only require one appointment for that day.  There is no
>   fee to make an appointment, but there is a $50 USD fee for each
>   document to be notarized that is paid at the Embassy. Please arrive 20
>   minutes prior to your appointment to allow sufficient time to pass
>   through Embassy security.

I've quoted the introduction, but to make an appointment you can do so on that page, and it'll also tell you what to bring.

The address of the embassy is:

American Embassy in Mexico City
Paseo de la Reforma 305
Colonia Cuauhtemoc
06500 Mexico, D.F.

More contact information is [available on their site](http://mexico.usembassy.gov/eacs_hours.html).

Comment: I found one, which isn't expressly recognized in the U.S., but satisfied my employer.

Comment: @Flimzy When you have time, perhaps you could add an answer as to HOW you found one, for future readers? I only ask, since even though you accepted Mark's $50 US Embassy answer, by your own comment it does not appear you used it.